# How to request input Iterations from users in python code

Tags: python, iteration

Pardon my cheap question, I am still a beginner!

Task: In the block of code below, I want the user to be able to try 3 wrong names,
and the program should possible print ‘you have reached the maximum attempts’
before the ‘Break’ command will execute. How can I achive this?

```
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Louis':
        print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
        name = input()
       #[I need to add some iterations here!]
        break
print('Thank you!')
```

Comment: Thing about of having a while loop which is determined from a counter. In this counter you will keep the wrong password entries and if the counter got 3 error inputs break the loop and print out the appropriate message

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should help. You just iterate over the number of attempts you want to give the user (here it is 3 attempts). You could also use the while True loop with a counter.

```
nbr_of_tries = 3
for i in range(nbr_of_tries):
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Louis':
        print('Thank you!')
        #[I need to add some iterations here!]
        break
    elif i < nbr_of_tries-1:
        print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
    else:
        print('Maximum number of tries reached. Exiting')
```

Comment: Where is the explanation of the answer?

Comment: @MichaelAdams I guess that twelve lines of code are really not that hard to understand, but I added some sort of explanation.

Comment: It's not about how hard is it to understand. Main part of the answer is explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tries=1
while True:
    name = input('Please type your name\n')
    if name != 'Louis':
        if tries!=3: #==== If tries is not equal to 3
            print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
            tries+=1 #=== Add 1 to tries
        else:
            print("You have reached maximum attempts.")
            break #=== Break out of loop

    else:
        print('Thank you!')
        break #=== Break out of loop
```

Comment: Any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    attempts = 3
    while attemps:
        if name != 'Louis':
            print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
            attempts -= 1
            name = input()
    else:
        print('maximum attempts reached')
print('Thank you!')
```

Explanation:
During the while loop the `attempts`-counter will be decremented if the `if` statement is True and the user can enter another name. If the counter reaches 0, the loop will stop and the `maximum attempts reached` message will be printed.

Comment: There's no explanation in you answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
x=0
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Louis':
        print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
        name = input()
       #[I need to add some iterations here!]
       if x==3:
           print("you have reached the limit")
           break
       else:
           x=x+1
           
    else:
        print('Thank you!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
while True:
    print('Please type your name')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Louis':
        print('Name is incorrect check and enter your name again!')
        count += 1
       #[I need to add some iterations here!]
        if count > 2:
            break
    else:
        print ("Required name entered")
        break
print('Thank you!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without break, something like this.

```
attempt = 0
while True and attempt < 3:
attempt += 1
print('Please type your name')
name = input()
if name != 'Louis':
  if attempt == 3:
   print('you have reached the maximum attempts')
  else:
   print('Name is incorrect. Please check and try again!')
 print('Thank you!')
```